# i need to change my tick color on my chart, i tried that and before tried yAxis and didnt work

Tags: javascript, chart.js

im using chartJs no my project for te first time, got some templates and read the docs.
But when i needed to change my tick color i couldnt.

this chart is a template, just put my values.

```
const dataOs = {
    labels: [
        'Minhas',
        'Encaminhadas'
    ],
    datasets: [{
        label: 'ordens de serviço',
        data: [64, 33],
        backgroundColor:[
            '#f7ff00',
            '#094490'
        ],
        borderWidth:1,
    }],
}
new Chart(chartOs, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: dataOs,
    options: {
        plugins:{
           scale: {
               y: {
                   ticks: {
                      color: '#000000'
                   }
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```